# webpack: ExtractTextPlugin outputs empty file

Tags: javascript, webpack, less

I'm taking all my css/less files and bundling them using the extract-text-webpack-plugin and then consuming it on my webpage but for some reason it is able to bundle bootstrap, material designs iconic font and several other vendor less files into an output file.  But when I try it with a customized less file the output is empty.  Not sure what is going on, thanks in advance.

**webpack.config.js**

```
'use strict';

const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const validate = require('webpack-validator');
const plugins = require('./plugins');

const PATHS = {
  app: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public', 'js', 'main.js'),
  build: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public', 'build'),
  style: [

    path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/less/variables.less')

  ]
};

const common = {
    entry: {
      app: PATHS.app,
      style: PATHS.style,
      vendor: [
       ....
      ]      
    },
    output: {
      path: PATHS.build,
      filename: '[name].js'  
    },
    target: 'web',
    module: {
      loaders: [             
        {test: /\.(woff|woff2)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff'},
        {test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream'},
        {test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'file'},
        {test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml'},
        {test: /\.json$/, loader: 'json' },
        {test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i, loader: 'url?limit=10000!img?progressive=true' },
        {test: /(\.tpl|\.html)$/, loader: 'underscore-template-loader' }
      ]
    }, 
    plugins: [
      // This context resolves warning from loading ./locales for moment.js
      new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/\.\/locale$/, 'empty-module', false, /js$/),
      // ProvidePlugin loads dependencies into global scope
      new webpack.ProvidePlugin({ 
          ....
      }),
      // CommonsChunkPlugin bundles all vendor modules
      new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin('vendor', 'vendor.js')
    ],
    resolve: {
      // Alias maps modules being used with different names to node_modules
      alias: {
        ....
      }
    }
  }

var config;

// Detect how npm is run and branch based on that
switch(process.env.npm_lifecycle_event) {
  case 'build:dev':
    config = merge(
      plugins.clean(PATHS.build),
      common,
      plugins.extractCSS(PATHS.style),
      { devtool: 'source-map' }     
    );
  break;
    default:
  config = merge(
      plugins.clean(PATHS.build),
      common,
      plugins.extractCSS(PATHS.style),
     { devtool: 'eval-source-map' }      
  );
}

module.exports = validate(config);
```

**plugins.js**

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

exports.extractCSS = function(paths) {
  return {
    module: {
      loaders: [
        {test: /\.css$/, loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader', 'css-loader'), include: paths},
        {test: /\.less$/, loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader', 'css-loader!less-loader'), include: paths}
      ]
    },
    plugins: [
      new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].css')
   ]
  };
}
```

**variables.less**

```
//
// Variables
// --------------------------------------------------


//== Colors
//
//## Gray and brand colors for use across Bootstrap.


@tone-brighter:           #fafbfc; //#fcfcfc;
@tone-bright:             #f0f3f5; //#f5f5f5;
@tone-bright-alt:         #edf0f2; //#f2f2f2;       


@gray-darker:           lighten(#040505, 20%); //lighten(#000, 20%);
@gray-dark:             lighten(#040505, 40%); //lighten(#000, 40%);
@gray:                  lighten(#040505, 60%); //lighten(#000, 60%);
@gray-light:            lighten(#040505, 80%); //lighten(#000, 80%);
@gray-lighter:          lighten(#040505, 90%); //lighten(#000, 90%);



@border-darker:            #dadfe3; //#e3e3e3;
@border-lighter:           #e6eaed; //#ededed;


// Brand colors
// -------------------------

@brand-default:         #ecf0f1;

@brand-inverse:         #95a5a6;
@brand-primary:         #3498db;
@brand-success:         #2ecc71;
@brand-warning:         #f1c40f;
@brand-danger:          #e74c3c;
@brand-info:            #3bbfb4;

@brand-brown:           #c0392b;
@brand-indigo:          #7863bc;
@brand-violet:          #9b59b6;
@brand-orange:          #e67e22;
@brand-midnightblue:    #34495e;
@brand-sky:             #82c4e6;
@brand-magenta:         #e73c68;
@brand-purple:          #e044ab;
@brand-green:           #37bf8d;
@brand-grape:           #7a869c;
@brand-toyo:            #556b8d;
@brand-alizarin:        #e36d4f;
@brand-blue:            #5394c9;
```

**style.css output file**

```
/*# sourceMappingURL=style.css.map*/
```

Comment: Do you actually add bootstrap somewhere? `@import ...`

Comment: I placed all my imports in a style.less file where i have the bootstrap import as well as several other imports including the variables.less file.  I had to resolve each of those one by one to figure out where my problem was and I figured out that these variables are not bundled along with my other files which is causing the problem.

Comment: It's perhaps generating an empty stylesheet because your app doesn't `require` any styles.

Comment: I'm guessing that the less pre-processor strips any unused variables and since this just contains variables none of the variables are used...